# Limit table in spotfire based on marked rows in another table

Tags: filtering, spotfire

I have 2 tables in my visualization. One is a list of tasks to be done, and one is a list of repairs that have been done at each location. I want to be able to filter the repairs table by the locations of the highlighted tasks. Ergo if you marked a task that takes place at location 1, the second table would filter to only show repairs for location 1. Is that something that's doable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Joseph, can you please post your table structures? You can probably achieve the desired result by creating a relation between your tables (Data Table Properties -> Relations -> Manage Relations)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do.  You need to create a relation on the Location column between your two tables (Data table properties, Relations tab).  Then create a details visualization (right click on "parent" table and select details visualization).  Because you have created the relation already, it will ask you which table you want to be the "child".  After selecting which table, you will be able to click on the parent, and it will filter in the child table.  Also note, using the right click menu is engaging the data limiting with marking, which you will be able to see in the properties dialog, data menu.  You don't have to use the right click menu to setup details visualizations.  It's just easy.

I've written a lot about how to use relations and column matches.  See links below.  Relations integrate filtering, which is what you want.  Column matches integrate marking.

https://www.bigmountainanalytics.com/apply-relations-and-column-matches-in-spotfire/
https://www.bigmountainanalytics.com/how-to-use-relations-in-spotfire/
https://www.bigmountainanalytics.com/how-to-use-column-matches-in-spotfire/